# Custom table header directives not behaving as expected

Tags: angularjs

I am putting together a directive that will wrap a transcluded table and will be used with another directive to prepend checkboxes to the first cell in a table row to allow for multi selections of rows, plus a header checkbox cell for toggle select\deselect-all functionality.

I have started with a table header directive, here is what I have come up with so far:

**DIRECTIVES**

```
angular
    .module('app.components')
    .directive('myTable', myTable);

function myTable() {
    var myTable = {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            someProperty: '='
        },
        template: '<div class="myTable">' +
                                '<md-toolbar class="md-menu-toolbar">' +
                                    '<div class="md-toolbar-tools">' +
                                        'OTHER CONTENT HERE...'
                                    '</div>' +
                                '</md-toolbar>' +
                                '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>' +
                            '</div>',
        controller: controller,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true
    };

    return myTable;

    function controller($attrs) {
        var self = this;
        self.enableMultiSelect = $attrs.multiple === '';
    }
}

angular
    .module('app.components')
    .directive('myTableHead', myTableHead);

myTableHead.$inject = ['$compile'];

function myTableHead($compile) {
    var myTableHead = {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: ['myTableHead', '^^myTable'],
        controller: controller,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true,
        link: link
    };

    return myTableHead;

    function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {

        var self = ctrls.shift(),
            tableCtrl = ctrls.shift();

        if(tableCtrl.enableMultiSelect){
            element.children().prepend(createCheckbox());
        }

        self.toggleAll = function () {
            console.log('toggleAll');
        };

        function createCheckbox() {
            var checkbox = angular.element('<md-checkbox>').attr({
                'aria-label': 'Select All',
                'ng-click': 'vm.toggleAll()'
            });

            return angular.element('<th class="md-column md-checkbox-column">').append($compile(checkbox)(scope));
        }
    }

    function controller() {

    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<my-table multiple>
    <table>
        <thead my-table-head>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                ...
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="thing in things">
                <td>{{thing.propA}}</td>
                <td>{{thing.propB}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</my-table>
```

I am encountering an issue where as soon as I have added the my-table-head directive to my thead element of the table being transcluded in, no rows from the ng-repeat get rendered.

The checkbox header cell does actually render just fine, but I also am finding when clicking it, the toggleAll function its bound to (defined in my link function) is not firing as I dont see any console log messages appearing.

I can't figure out why, can anyone point out what I am doing wrong with my approach above?

Comment: `<div>` is invalid inside a table except in cells

Comment: OK - but I don't have any div's inside the table transcluded in

Comment: oops ..my bad...was looking at wrong directive. Create a demo that reproduces problem